Can't add the DAX measures to the columns
I have a table



Date
Customer
Sales




Feb-24
Ian
2


Mar-24
Ian
5


Apr-24
Ian
7


May-24
Ian
10



I want to create a table matrix that looks like this



Customer
Feb24
Mar24
Apr24
May24
Q1 Sales
Q2 Sales
Q1 - Q2 Growth




Ian
2
5
7
10
7
17
143



I have a matrix and put Customer in the rows and Date in the columns.
I also have DAX measures to create calculations for Q1  Sales, Q2 Sales and Q1-Q2 Growth.
I can't add the DAX measures to the columns. Is there a workaround?

Here is a workaround for you.

Created a new table



sort the column1 by sort column



create a date2 column in original table


Do not create relationship between tables and create a measure
MEASURE =
SWITCH (
TRUE (),
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Column1] )
IN { "Feb-24", "Mar-24", "Apr-24", "May-24" },
CALCULATE (
SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ),
'Table'[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Column1] )
),
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Column1] ) = "Q1 Sales", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ), QUARTER ( 'Table'[Date2] ) = 1 ),
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Column1] ) = "Q2 Sales", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ), QUARTER ( 'Table'[Date2] ) = 2 ),
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Column1] ) = "Q1 - Q2 Growth",
(
DIVIDE (
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ), QUARTER ( 'Table'[Date2] ) = 2 ),
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ), QUARTER ( 'Table'[Date2] ) = 1 )
) - 1
) * 100
)





If you want an easy setup this transformation could be done with excel using pivot table, you can either export your table from power bi visual or save your table as an excel file. after performing pivot table you can re import it again in your power BI data model
